# SharePoint 2019 OnPrem - SPFx 1.4.1 development environment compatibility

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, sharepoint-2019

I recently set up a new workstation and began testing the new environment. Unfortunately, I'm encountering issues when attempting to run 'yo @microsofst/sharepoint' for scaffolding.

Here are the current versions I'm using:

Node v16.15.0 | NPM v6.14.11

```
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.4.1
+-- generator-generator@5.1.0
+-- gulp@4.0.2
+-- gulp-cli@2.3.0
+-- npm@6.14.11
+-- yarn@1.22.21
+-- yeoman-environment@4.1.3
`-- yo@3.1.1
```

yo doctor:

```
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

√ No .bowerrc file in home directory
√ Global configuration file is valid
√ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
√ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
√ Node.js version
√ npm version
× yo version
```

Your yo version is outdated.

```
When I run yo:
Make sure you are in the directory you want to scaffold into.
This generator can also be run with: yo @microsoft/sharepoint

Error

This generator (@microsoft/sharepoint:app) requires yeoman-environment at least 3.0.0, current version is 2.10.3, try reinstalling latest version of 'yo' or use '--ignore-version-check' option
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0
corepack@0.10.0
gulp-cli@2.3.0
npm@8.5.5
yo@2.0.6
```

with nodejs version - 8.17.0